# Looking for software to create and manage test sequences

Tags: automated-testing, tools

I am working on embedded firmware that provides a lot of functions through an ethernet interface. I would like to test the function by writing test programs in C# or python that test specific functions. Now I am looking for software that allows me to create complex test sequences consisting of my small test programs.

Does anyone know a good open source tool to do this?

Do you this this approach is a good idea?

Comment: It not answer, but reminder: Even if you need to run in .NET environment, you can use still Python: IronPython can use .NET but has all the flexibility of Python. Pretty neat. :-) So if you cannot find one, build yourself something in Python. Sounds like a good project to get open-sourced!

Answer (score 2):

It is a good idea, there are many tools available.

I heard good things about [Robot Framework](http://robotframework.org/) and [Nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), both are in Python.

Robot Framework has built in capability to read from configuration files, so your task of creating test sequences would be easier, although the same can be done very easily with "pure" Python.